# Changing an image to fit a Div

Tags: html, css

I am trying to place my image in a div of 120 X 120 px though when i preview in browser its just a empty box, i presume that this is because i am editing the size of the div not the actual box,

Here is my CSS code;

```
#logo
{
background-image:url("../img/LOGO1.png");
height:120px;
width:120px;
}
```

and my HtML is ;

```
<div id="logo">
</div>
```

so all I'm trying to do is  compress an image to fit my div size,

Thankyou very much

Comment: What browser support is needed? Can we neglect IE<8?

Comment: Use background-size:cover or background-size:contain

Comment: iMoses, i am aiming it towards google chrome and safari, though all browser support would be nice

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `background-size`. Either use:

```
-webkit-background-size:120px; /* webkit support */
-o-background-size:120px; /* opera support */
background-size:120px;
```

or use:

```
-webkit-background-size:cover; /* webkit support */
-o-background-size:cover; /* opera support */
background-size:cover; //or contain
```

Comment: would i use background-size:contain;

Comment: or would i use cover?

Comment: @bjbear123 it's the same thing in your case if the background image is square.

Comment: @otinanai Don't forget to add `-webkit-background-size:cover; -moz-background-size:cover; -o-background-size:cover;` to make the code cross-browser.

Comment: @DanielLisik you're absolutely correct! No need for `moz` prefix though.

Comment: @otinanai is `moz` not needed in just this situation or could one skip it completely?

Comment: @DanielLisik you can skip it completely in mozilla but you still need it for Opera and some webkit browsers.